# How to add a progress bar to one of my CListCtrl columns?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I've found the following CodeGuru examples on how to add a progress bar to the ListCtrl: [Example 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6813/List-Control-Extended-for-Progress-Control), [Example 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1342/Adding-progress-bars-to-a-list-control), [Example 3](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/article.php/c4187/Embed-Progress-Bars-in-a-List-Control.htm). Unfortunately they're all pretty bad. In the most [highly rated one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6813/List-Control-Extended-for-Progress-Control), the guy literally creates a new CProgressCtrl from within the OnPaint message for the CListCtrl, which creates an awful flicker (besides 20 other issues), and is outright wrong. The rest of the examples are pretty buggy as well.

So I started thinking if there's a better way of adding a progress bar to my CListCtrl-derived class? I'm kinda inclining towards making it an owner-drawn control and actually drawing my own progress bar in a list-ctrl's column cell. But since it would be nice to preserve the OS look and feel of the progress bar, I'm curious if there's a way to "paint" it using its default look?

So I'm curious if I'm on the right track? And if not, what is your proposed way of implementing it?

PS. If I create CProgressCtrl as a child control the issue that I'm seeing at this point is how to scroll it along with the parent CListCtrl...

Comment: Owner-drawing is the way to go. If Visual Styles are enabled, you can use [`DrawThemeBackground()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289.aspx) to draw the various components of a progress bar using the OS's current theme. If Visual Styles are not enabled, you will have to draw the progress bar manually, as [`DrawFrameControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162480.aspx) does not support drawing progress bars.